# Get the wrong path when execute python code by Nodejs

Tags: python, node.js

I am using [python-shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) to call a python script from my nodejs server. The python script will open a file named **myfile.txt** and read its content:

`path = os.path.abspath("myfile.txt")
f = open(path, 'r')`

It runs normally when I execute the python code from Python command line but when I try to call it from Nodejs, turns out that the **path** became "path-to-nodejs-server/bin/myfile.txt" and I catch an error "**No such file/ directory ..**"

How can I fix it?

Comment: is the file in the same directory as python? in which case you could replace `os.path.abspath("myfile.txt")` by `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"myfile.txt")`

Comment: Yes the file is in the same directory as python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
os.path.abspath("myfile.txt")
```

doesn't fix anything (unless you use `os.chdir` at some point, but that's not the case here)

The problem here is that you don't have a say on the current directory when your python script is run from nodejs.

*but* you know where your data file is stored relatively from your script.

Since `__file__` contains the absolute path of your script you can locate your data file by:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"myfile.txt")
```